# Accessing RTSP Server hosted on AWS over internet

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ffmpeg, rtsp

I am trying to access my EC2 Ubuntu instance from AWS using gaminganywhere (gaminganywhere.org). The security group policy is to allow all connections, but couldn't connect to the server. Here is the log from the client and server.

Client

```
# [7860] 1522686205.894230 # include: config/common/controller.conf
# [7860] 1522686205.894569 # include: config/common/video-x264.conf
# [7860] 1522686205.894755 # include: config/common/audio-lame.conf
# [7860] 1522686205.895002 # RTSP[config]: using 'udp' for RTP flows.
# [7860] 1522686205.895012 # RTSP[config]: controller port = 8555
# [7860] 1522686205.895016 # RTSP[config]: controller via 'udp' protocol.
# [7860] 1522686205.895058 # RTSP[config]: video-encoder = libx264 (libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10)
# [7860] 1522686205.895071 # RTSP[config]: audio-encoder = libmp3lame (libmp3lame MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3))
# [7860] 1522686205.895101 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: threads = auto
Remote server @ 18.188.161.135[18.188.161.135]:8554
# [7860] 1522686205.971505 SDL: prefer opengl hardware renderer.
# [7860] 1522686205.971532 controller queue: initialized size=32708 (481 units)
# [7860] 1522686205.971693 controller socket: socket address [18.188.161.135:8555]
# [7860] 1522686205.971727 controller client-thread started: tid=7863.
watchdog: launched, waiting for audio/video frames ...
# [7860] 1522686205.971813 rtspclient: max tolerable video delay disabled.
*** SAVEFILE: YUV image saved to 'NULL'; timestamp saved to 'NULL'.
RTP reordering threshold = 300000
# [7860] 1522686205.971959 qos-measurement: initialized.
Opening connection to 18.188.161.135, port 8554...
...remote connection opened
Sending request: DESCRIBE rtsp://18.188.161.135:8554/desktop RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: RTSP Client (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27)
Accept: application/sdp


Received 619 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete DESCRIBE response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 2
Date: Mon, Apr 02 2018 16:23:26 GMT
Content-Base: rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 456

v=0
o=- 1522685876960515 1 IN IP4 10.0.0.73
s=GamingAnywhere Server
i=desktop
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:GamingAnywhere Server
a=x-qt-text-inf:desktop
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:3000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4D4020;sprop-parameter-sets=Z01AILaAUAIGhAAAAwAEAAADAMI8YMqA,aO88gA==
a=control:track1

[URL:"rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/"]: Got a SDP description:
v=0
o=- 1522685876960515 1 IN IP4 10.0.0.73
s=GamingAnywhere Server
i=desktop
t=0 0
a=tool:LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27
a=type:broadcast
a=control:*
a=range:npt=0-
a=x-qt-text-nam:GamingAnywhere Server
a=x-qt-text-inf:desktop
m=video 0 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
b=AS:3000
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1;profile-level-id=4D4020;sprop-parameter-sets=Z01AILaAUAIGhAAAAwAEAAADAMI8YMqA,aO88gA==
a=control:track1

# [7860] 1522686206.581278 qos-measurement: source #0 added, prefix=-281002320
video decoder: use decoder h264
video decoder(0): sprop configured with 'Z01AILaAUAIGhAAAAwAEAAADAMI8YMqA,aO88gA==', decoded-size=36
SPROP = [ 00 00 00 01 67 4d 40 20 b6 80 50 02 06 84 00 00 03 00 04 00 00 03 00 c2 3c 60 ca 80 00 00 00 01 68 ef 3c 80 ]
video decoder(0): codec h264 (H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10)
video decoder(0) initialized (client port 44578)
[URL:"rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/"]: Initiated the "video/H264" subsession (client ports 44578-44579)
Sending request: SETUP rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/track1 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 3
User-Agent: RTSP Client (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27)
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;client_port=44578-44579


Received 212 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete SETUP response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 3
Date: Mon, Apr 02 2018 16:23:26 GMT
Transport: RTP/AVP;unicast;destination=117.206.20.30;source=10.0.0.73;client_port=44578-44579;server_port=6970-6971
Session: CBA2E074;timeout=65


[URL:"rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/"]: Set up the "video/H264" subsession (client ports 44578-44579)
[URL:"rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/"]: Created a data sink for the "video/H264" subsession
Receiver buffer increased to 2097152
NAT hole punching: fd=11, local-port=44578/44578 server-port=6970
Sending request: PLAY rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/ RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 4
User-Agent: RTSP Client (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2014.05.27)
Session: CBA2E074
Range: npt=0.000-


watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
Received 184 new bytes of response data.
Received a complete PLAY response:
RTSP/1.0 200 OK
CSeq: 4
Date: Mon, Apr 02 2018 16:23:27 GMT
Range: npt=0.000-
Session: CBA2E074
RTP-Info: url=rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/track1;seq=32456;rtptime=2677630715


[URL:"rtsp://10.0.0.73:8554/desktop/"]: Started playing session...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
watchdog: initialized, but no frames received ...
```

Server

```
# [4432] 1522685876.873593 # include: config/common/server-common.conf
# [4432] 1522685876.873731 # include: config/common/controller.conf
# [4432] 1522685876.873810 # include: config/common/video-x264.conf
# [4432] 1522685876.873882 # include: config/common/video-x264-param.conf
# [4432] 1522685876.873974 # include: config/common/audio-lame.conf
# [4432] 1522685876.874060 # RTSP[config]: using 'udp' for RTP flows.
# [4432] 1522685876.874100 # RTSP[config]: controller port = 8555
# [4432] 1522685876.874131 # RTSP[config]: controller via 'udp' protocol.
# [4432] 1522685876.874189 # RTSP[config]: video-encoder = libx264 (libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10)
# [4432] 1522685876.874230 # RTSP[config]: audio-encoder = libmp3lame (libmp3lame MP3 (MPEG audio layer 3))
# [4432] 1522685876.874281 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: b = 3000000
# [4432] 1522685876.874316 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: g = 48
# [4432] 1522685876.874348 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: intra-refresh = 1
# [4432] 1522685876.874378 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: me_method = dia
# [4432] 1522685876.874410 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: me_range = 16
# [4432] 1522685876.874440 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: preset = faster
# [4432] 1522685876.874471 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: profile = main
# [4432] 1522685876.874501 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: refs = 1
# [4432] 1522685876.874532 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: slices = 4
# [4432] 1522685876.874563 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: threads = 4
# [4432] 1522685876.874594 # RTSP[config]: video specific option: tune = zerolatency
# [4432] 1522685876.874625 *** Crop disabled.
# [4432] 1522685876.878908 sink server: live555-rtsp-server registered
# [4432] 1522685876.878957 key-blocking initialized: 0+0 keys blocked.
# [4432] 1522685876.879015 sdl_replayer: sizeof(sdlmsg) = 64
# [4432] 1522685876.879465 sdl replayer: Replay using XTest (version 2.2) for display :0 screen 0, size=1280x1024.
# [4432] 1522685876.879793 XShm extention version 1.2 with shared pixmaps
# [4432] 1522685876.879832 X-Window-init: dimension: 1280x1024x8 @ 0/1
# [4432] 1522685876.879917 dpipe: 'video-0' initialized, 8 frames, framesize = 16384092
# [4432] 1522685876.913130 video-source: video-0 initialized max-curr-out = (2560x1600)-(1280x1024)-(1280x1024)
# [4432] 1522685876.914241 Frame converter created: from (1280,1024)[30] -> (1280,1024)[0]
# [4432] 1522685876.914343 dpipe: 'filter-0' initialized, 8 frames, framesize = 16384092
# [4432] 1522685876.948463 video encoder: video source #0 from 'filter-0' (1280x1024).
# [4432] 1522685876.948720 vencoder-init: option b = 3000000
# [4432] 1522685876.948755 vencoder-init: option g = 48
# [4432] 1522685876.948783 vencoder-init: option intra-refresh = 1
# [4432] 1522685876.948811 vencoder-init: option me_method = dia
# [4432] 1522685876.948839 vencoder-init: option me_range = 16
# [4432] 1522685876.948867 vencoder-init: option preset = faster
# [4432] 1522685876.948894 vencoder-init: option profile = main
# [4432] 1522685876.948921 vencoder-init: option refs = 1
# [4432] 1522685876.948949 vencoder-init: option slices = 4
# [4432] 1522685876.948977 vencoder-init: option threads = 4
# [4432] 1522685876.949004 vencoder-init: option tune = zerolatency
[libx264 @ 0x9518b40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0x9518b40] profile Main, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0x9518b40] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=dia subme=4 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=48 keyint_min=4 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=1 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=3000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
# [4432] 1522685876.958913 video encoder: initialized.
# [4432] 1522685876.959008 video encoder: ffmpeg-video-encoder registered
# [4432] 1522685876.959137 RGB2YUV filter[4443]: pipe#0 from 'video-0' to 'filter-0' (output-resolution=1280x1024)
# [4432] 1522685876.959229 video source thread started: tid=4442
# [4432] 1522685876.959290 controller socket: socket address [0.0.0.0:8555]
# [4432] 1522685876.959337 controller server started: tid=4441.
# [4432] 1522685876.960458 encoder: packet queue initialized (3x3145728 bytes)
# [4432] 1522685876.960516 qos-measurement: initialized.
# [4432] 1522685876.960587 (Use port 8000 for optional RTSP-over-HTTP tunneling.)
# [4432] 1522685983.386797 video encdoer: all started (1)
# [4432] 1522685983.386926 encoder client registered: total 1 clients.
# [4432] 1522685983.386990 encoder: pktqueue #0 callback registered (0xf55a88a0)
# [4432] 1522685983.387065 video encoder: h.264/found sps@4(24); pps@32(4)
# [4432] 1522685983.387118 GAMediaSubsession: video/H264 SPS=0xdcfc346c(24); PPS=0xdcfc356c(4); profile_level_id=4d4020
# [4432] 1522685983.387191 qos: add sink#1 for H.264, rtpsink=0xdc6061f8
# [4432] 1522685983.387255 encoder client unregistered: 0 clients left.
# [4432] 1522685983.387290 encoder: no more clients, quitting ...
# [4432] 1522685983.387355 video encoding started: tid=4445 1280x1024@24fps, nalbuf_size=15828640, pic_in_size=1966080.
# [4432] 1522685983.387402 video encoder: thread terminated (tid=4445).
# [4432] 1522685983.387446 video encdoer: all stopped (1)
[libx264 @ 0x9518b40] final ratefactor: 23.57
# [4432] 1522685983.388265 video encoder: deinitialized.
# [4432] 1522685983.741415 video encoder: video source #0 from 'filter-0' (1280x1024).
# [4432] 1522685983.741772 vencoder-init: option b = 3000000
# [4432] 1522685983.741819 vencoder-init: option g = 48
# [4432] 1522685983.741870 vencoder-init: option intra-refresh = 1
# [4432] 1522685983.741926 vencoder-init: option me_method = dia
# [4432] 1522685983.741975 vencoder-init: option me_range = 16
# [4432] 1522685983.742020 vencoder-init: option preset = faster
# [4432] 1522685983.742086 vencoder-init: option profile = main
# [4432] 1522685983.742123 vencoder-init: option refs = 1
# [4432] 1522685983.742154 vencoder-init: option slices = 4
# [4432] 1522685983.742188 vencoder-init: option threads = 4
# [4432] 1522685983.742218 vencoder-init: option tune = zerolatency
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX AVX2 FMA3 LZCNT BMI2
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] profile Main, level 3.2
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] 264 - core 142 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2014 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=1 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=dia subme=4 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=0 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=0 threads=4 lookahead_threads=4 sliced_threads=1 slices=4 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=0 weightp=1 keyint=48 keyint_min=4 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=1 rc=abr mbtree=0 bitrate=3000 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
# [4432] 1522685983.749123 video encoder: initialized.
# [4432] 1522685983.749175 video encdoer: all started (1)
# [4432] 1522685983.749209 encoder client registered: total 1 clients.
# [4432] 1522685983.749241 encoder: pktqueue #0 callback registered (0xf55a88a0)
# [4432] 1522685983.749301 video encoder: h.264/found sps@4(24); pps@32(4)
# [4432] 1522685983.749336 GAMediaSubsession: video/H264 SPS=0xdcfc353c(24); PPS=0xdcfc363c(4); profile_level_id=4d4020
# [4432] 1522685983.749385 qos: add sink#1 for H.264, rtpsink=0xe3471b60
# [4432] 1522685983.749480 video encoding started: tid=4454 1280x1024@24fps, nalbuf_size=15828640, pic_in_size=1966080.
# [4432] 1522685983.775570 first video frame written (pts=0)
# [4432] 1522686049.085120 encoder client unregistered: 0 clients left.
# [4432] 1522686049.085221 encoder: no more clients, quitting ...
# [4432] 1522686049.102929 video encoder: thread terminated (tid=4454).
# [4432] 1522686049.103052 video encdoer: all stopped (1)
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] frame I:1     Avg QP: 7.00  size:   447
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] frame P:1568  Avg QP: 0.01  size:   216
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] mb I  I16..4: 99.9%  0.0%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] mb P  I16..4:  3.2%  0.0%  0.0%  P16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:96.8%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] final ratefactor: -29.32
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0% inter: 0.0% 0.0% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] i16 v,h,dc,p: 94%  0%  6%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu:  0%  0% 100%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] i8c dc,h,v,p: 100%  0%  0%  0%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0xdc605f40] kb/s:41.58
# [4432] 1522686049.104181 video encoder: deinitialized.
```

I think the IP address in RTSP header is the LAN IP of the device which is causing the making the connection to fail. The same software works fine from the LAN. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Probably because the dynamically allocated UDP ports are not allowed by the security group. A simple solution could be to use  RTP over TCP that is supported by live555 on client & server side.

Comment: I have enabled all ports in the security policy. The issue is mostly because the server returns the lan ip in rtsp describe header. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: You can set the global `ReceivingInterfaceAddr` to the interface you like.

Answer (score 0):

The gaminganywhere client might not receive the stream if you are behind a NAT.

As it happens, I tried the same thing this week. I set up a gaminganywhere server on a EC2 instance, and a client on my machine, and I observed the exact behavior you are describing. ("no frames received ...", private IP in the DESCRIBE reply...). At first I also thought that the private IP sent by the server was the issue, but **in my case, I didn't receive the stream simply because I was behind a NAT**.

I tried to open the RTSP URL with vlc, and... It worked. After examining the traffic with wireshark, it seems that VLC first asked the server to send the stream via UDP, and after a couple of seconds where no UDP packet reached my machine, it asked again for the stream, this time asking for TCP. Then TCP packets flowed and streaming ensued.

Back to GA, I couldn't find a configuration option (edit: disregard this paragraph) to force the client to ask for TCP, even though the code seems to allow for it. So I compiled the client after modifying the code to force the use of TCP, and this time the streaming worked. (My change was quick and dirty: I added `rtpOverTCP = true` in `rtspclient.cpp` right before the call to `rtspClient->sendSetupCommand()`.)

EDIT: After a more careful examination of the code, the `core.proto` defined in the server configuration should be in the client configuration. I can't test, but adding `core.proto = tcp` in the client configuration should work.

(Note: there is a "NAT hole punching" feature mentionned in the changelog of gaminganywhere. Not sure what it is or if it could help.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But i found another quick solution. Switching the ga server port to default RTSP port worked for me. I don't remember whether i changed the protocol to tcp. But it was working fine on default port.